# Delegated vs Application permission scenarios

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

There is an ad-hoc request from a user in my organisation whereby the below permissions have been sought:

- Reports.Read.All
- User.Read.All
- Organization.Read.All
- Directory.Read.All

Now **delegated permissions** is not working out for the user and he has specifically sought **Application Permissions**. Now if we approve this request, does this mean the user's application would have access to all the reports in the organisation, for the entire tenant? Can this involve some sensitive information as well? Would this access mean that details of all the users (name, employee id, reporting manager details, phone number, address) be available to the application (in read-only format)? Similarly having privilege like **Directory.Read.All** as an Application permission would mean the application can read everything in the organisation related to user groups and all apps that the entire organisation is using?

Is there a way to restrict **Application Permission**?

Comment: Can you inquire and add here why these permissions are needed?  It's an unusual request, and often caused by a misunderstanding of how to grant permissions to a Service Principal in the target service.  If this is an on-behalf-of scenario, granting admin consent is really not a good solution, and they should just fix the underlying problem.

Comment: but why would any application wont work on delegated permission if the aforementioned permissions are only granted? so those permissions as delegated or as application permission, what difference would it make for the user application?